# Outputting Matrix Loop in Template

Tags: templating, matrix, forloop

I have looked at documentation and I still can't figure out how to output the matrix to my template.

The Field handle name is: **threeHomepageImages**

The Block type handle name is: **images**

The Fields names are: **image**, **alt**, and **imageTitle**

I have the following and tried a few combinations, but no luck. Any help is much appreciated.

```
{% for block in entry.threeHomepageImages.type('images') %}
    {{ image }} {{ alt }} {{ imageTitle }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're pretty close, but those field names need to be called as attributes on `block`:

```
{% for block in entry.threeHomepageImages.type('images') %}
    {% if block.image|length %}
        {{ block.image.first }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ block.alt }} {{ block.imageTitle }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm assuming your `image` field is an [Assets Field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#examples) here, so you need to first check that any exist, then select the first one.

Answer (score 5):

You're almost there.

Every block returns a MatrixBlockModel, so you have to reference your block when getting the attributes:

```
{% for block in entry.threeHomepageImages.type('images') %}
    <h2>{{ block.imageTitle }}</h2>
    {# Save images to variable for reuse #}
    {% set image = block.image %}
    {# Check if there is any images #}
    {% if image | length %}
        {# Get url #}
        {% set image = image.first().getUrl() %}
        <img src="{{ image }}" alt="{{ block.alt }}" /> 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```